# tabBarController set to nil when changing view but always in the window

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tabbar, swipe

I'm currently using a tableview inside a navigation controller, inside a tab bar controller. When i'm on the detail view of the table view, i want to "swipe" between Detail view, so i have implemented a UISwipeGesture with UIViewAnimations to swipe right/left.
Everything is working, but I have a little problem... When i'm on a Detail View loaded from the table view, the self.tabBarController element is here, i have my tab bar so i can add an actionsheet on it. But when i swipe, the self.tabBarController is nil now... I don't know why... Maybe because of the navigation Controller ?

Here is my code :

```
- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
        UIScrollView *scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, fullScreenRect.size.width, 367.)];
        scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,100);
        scrollView.delegate = self;
        self.view=scrollView;
        self.myView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 367.)];
        self.ButtonSizeM.tag = 0;
        self.ButtonSizeP.tag = 0;
        self.ContentIV = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) handleSwipeLeft {
   if (!((self.ancient.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.section == ([self.ancient numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.ancient.tableView] - 1)) && (self.ancient.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row == [self.ancient tableView:self.ancient.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(self.ancient.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.section)]-1)))
    {
        NSIndexPath *whereToGo;
        if (self.ancient.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row == [self.ancient tableView:self.ancient.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(self.ancient.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.section)]-1) {
            whereToGo = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:(self.ancient.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.section)+1];
        }
        else {
            whereToGo = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(self.ancient.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row)+1 inSection:self.ancient.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.section];
        }

        CCFASimpleDetail *nextView = [[CCFASimpleDetail alloc] init];
        nextView = [self.ancient tableView:self.ancient.tableView prepareViewForIndexPath:whereToGo];
        [nextView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(affichageEnPlace) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

        float width = self.myView.frame.size.width;
        float height = self.myView.frame.size.height;

        [nextView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(width, 0.0, width, height)];

        [self.view addSubview:nextView.view];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                [nextView.view setFrame:self.view.frame];
                [self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake(-width, 0.0, width, height)];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                [self.myView removeFromSuperview];
                [self.ancient.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:whereToGo animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
            }
         ];
    }
}
```

I you could help me to find my tab bar after swiping :) ?

Comment: Why are you calling `performSelectorOnMainThread:...`? All of this should be done on the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem by adding

```
[self.ancient.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self.ancient.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:NO];
```

on the completion block !

Answer (score 0):

When you add the view here:

```
[self.view addSubview:nextView.view];
```

the UINavigation controller does not know about it, and does not set the navigationBar nad tabBar properties for you.

What you can do is have the view get its superview (which will be self.view), then ask that view for the tabBarController and tabBar from that.